# Show panel custom label activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am having this `show` code in Post Resource in Active Admin:

```
show do |post|
  attributes_table do
    rows :name, :author, :category
  end
end
```

I just want custom label but the panel always gives `Post Details` as the label of the panel. I want it to be like `Your Blog Details`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show title: 'Your Blog Details' do |post|
  attributes_table do
    rows :name, :author, :category
  end
end
```

[Reference](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/set-page-title).

Comment: what if i am having different tabs and i want different labels for every panel inside that panel the object of same post will work

Comment: @Rishabh If this answer solves your issue, please make sure to accept it. As to your comment - I do not understand it, so please, ask a new question with example and desired output (do not edit the current question, because it will invalidate my answer).